# User Account Missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, data-recovery, user-accounts, user

I am on Windows 10, and I performed a Windows Update, and then after the computer restarted, my user account was empty, all my personal files are gone, nothing in the documents, desktop, downloads. It appears my user account is now missing. I performed a system restore, but it only recovered a small amount of files. I used a data recovery software, but it only recovered very old files, not recent ones.

What is the cause of this issue? Where are my files? Was my user account deleted? How do I recover my files? If I need to recover a missing user account, how do I do that? There are no more System Restore Points left to use. There is no need to suggest using a Windows Image Restore, I would have already used that. Thank you.

Comment: You may be logged in with a Temporary profile. Try restarting to see if you can log in correctly.  Use Windows Explorer to look in C;\USERS  . Is your user folder there?  You may be able to recover documents from it and make a new profile.

Comment: "What is the cause of this issue?" - You likely were logged into a temporary profile.  However, since you used a restore point, any chance of diagnosing the cause is lost.  "Where are my files?" - You would have to confirm, you are looking in your actual user profile directory for the files, if you are then they are likely lost due to the actions you took. "Was my user account deleted?" - You will have to provide us more information to determine this.  Sadly, based on the information you have provided, your question cannot be currently answered.

Answer (score 0):

If this was [KB4532693](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/february-11-2020-kb4532693-os-builds-18362-657-and-18363-657-e354da0e-d975-65a9-cf53-375203936283), then there is a **[known issue](https://betanews.com/2020/02/13/windows-10-kb4532693-lost-user-profile/) with that Windows update causing loss (or hiding) the user's profile**. See Microsoft's [explanation of that issue and possible remedies](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/kb4532693-and-4244-fix/d1a84bef-d30d-485a-b8ad-8c73fbd2c844).

If you're lucky, the data may still be on the disk.

Also note recent issues with [BSD and printing in the Mach 2021 update](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/windows-10-emergency-updates-released-to-fix-printing-crashes/), a separate issue. Before installing Windows updates, it's useful wait a few days to check for issues.